# Vue.js Sortable list - updating model and saving position on change through AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel-5.1, jquery-ui-sortable, vue.js

#### Fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/fierflash/0h6uL4ek/2/

#### Objective:

When a re-order takes place(through Sortable), send a AJAX Request to backend to save the new positions of the tasks

#### Whats v-sortable?

http://am2studio.hr/blog/creating-dynamic-table-with-vue-js/

#### Problem

- The markup is updated but the model is not updated. In this case the value of task.position remains the same when a re-order takes place.
- How should the `$watch` look like for this(if needed)? What values should I put in?

How to solve this?

Comment: We'll probably need to see your javascript to help. A jsfiddle would be even better.

Comment: @DavidK.Hess Ofcourse, added a fiddle, no AJAX done there since I'm not sure where and the model is not updating right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem you are running into with that approach is you are trying to update the position by using an `input` with `type="hidden"`. Vue's `v-model` does not support that input type (and unfortunately doesn't emit an error message in that case either).

Since you are just trying to update the position after the drop ends, why not just walk the array and set it afterwards like this?

```
that.value.forEach(function (task, index) {
    task.position = index + 1;
});
```

Working fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/zuwg1dh6/1/